# Django - Ajax call made even after logout from a page loaded by clicking back button in browser

Tags: django

When i logout and press Back button in Browser, the page loads and the links inside it also pop up into new page. and also ajax calls on, say button click, makes an ajax request, for which the response contains the html of the login page. but, the page is not redirected to login page.

My question is how to prevent the links to pop up in new window and how to redirect to login page when an ajax call is made?

However, when i hit refresh button, the login page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you press the return button in your browser the page is loaded from the browsers cache. I suppose you could clear the cache after a logout.

[read more](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/135121/Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout)

Anyway if the user logged out, presses return invoking an ajax call he or she will not get a valid data return if authentication is required. Example:

```
ajax.py

def get_inbox_messages_count(request):
    data = {}
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        return data = { ... }
```

Clicking the previous button, as expected, does NOT invoke a data return.